# How to create a blog page, show all posts and change the blog post url structure in a wordpress installed website

Tags: wordpress, blogs

Hello I am a little new to wordpress. I know how to create website & theme in wordpress. But when I am going to create a blog page for website, I am able to show all posts in blog page but unable to change the url structure. Ex yourwebsite.com/blog/postname. If any plugin is there please tell me. Any help will be appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I found the answer.

1 - Create a page like www.yourwebsite.com/blog

2 -  Setting -> Permalink -> Custom Structure -> Add /blog before /%postname%/ -> Save

3 -  Setting -> Reading -> Postpage -> select your blog page(where you want to appear your post)

This works for me. Hope it helps you.